# Drupal automatic URL alias removing words

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on a website that is built in Drupal 7. For the URL path settings for the pages I'm creating, I would like to use the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting.

There's a minor problem in that the automatically generated URL seems to automatically remove the word "with", and for all I know may remove other words as well. For example, I'm working on a page that is titled **"Talk with Your Child about their Illness"** and the automatically generated URL alias is "**talk-your-child-about-their-illness"**. How can I change the settings so the word "with" will be automatically included in the URL alias, and how can I tell what other words might be excluded?

I looked through the URL Aliases page and thought I might find something in the replacement patterns section, but if it's in there I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `/admin/config/search/path/settings`, there is a textarea labeled **Strings to Remove**. This textarea contains a comma-separated list of words "to strip out of the URL alias".

The [default list](https://drupal.org/node/847370) contains "with".

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find. Thank you so much!